# Determine if first player can win a game or not

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

> Consider the following game. There's an array of positive numbers. Each player in turn removes a slice (consecutive sequence of elements) such that it's sum is even. The player to lose is the player that cannot make a move.
>   For the `[4, 5, 3, 7, 2]` example, the winning strategy (for first player) is removing the`[5,3]`slice.
>   You need to determine if the first player has a winning move (if yes, return the `slice_start` and `slice_end` indexes).
>
> Time/Space complexity: `O(n)`

One natural thing I came up with is to calculate the accumulative sum from left to right and vice versa. In the `[4,5,3,7,2]` example we get:
`acc_l = [4,9,12,19,21]` and `acc_r = [21,17,12,9,2]`.

So I'm almost certain those two auxiliary arrays should come in handy but I couldn't figure it out completely.

I'd be glad for help!

Comment: Can you remove all numbers?

Comment: Yes, you can. @libik

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Calculate sum of whole array. Check if it's even or odd. Also count number of even and odd numbers in the array (all in one pass). That should help you figure out your answer.

Comment: Should this info be used in addition to the accumulative sum arrays? It seems to me that this information alone isn't sufficient.

Comment: This is not sufficient: `0 1 0` is a loss for the first player, but `1 0 0` is a win for the first player.

Comment: @user3080953 - good point. So I suppose this is the solution: Sum is even=you remove all numbers and win. Sum is odd=, check if the odd number is in beginning or the end of the array. If so, remove all the numbers beside this one. If not = there is no winning move.

Comment: @libik Agree with the even sum, but `0 1 1 1 0` is a win for the first player but doesn't start or end with an odd number

Comment: @user3080953 - its not, the second player wins

Comment: No, it's congruent to the case in the question. The winning move is to take two of the ones: `0 1 1 1 0` => `0 1 0`, which is a losing position